# React Native how to play a sound after an "onPress"?

Tags: react-native, onpress, react-native-sound

Here is some of my code:

```
<TouchableOpacity
       style={styles.button}
       onPress={this.onPress}
       >
       <Text> Play Sound </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I want to write a function "onPress" which will play an .mp3 sound. 
I have already imported **react-native-sound** and have my .mp3 file ready to go, I just don't know how to play the sound once the onPress function is called.

Comment: The docs bro, the docs!  https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,  if you want to listen the sound, you can try this.
 Syntax = react.

```
Import Sound from "react-native-sound";

Sound.setCategory('Playback');
const whoosh = new Sound('whoosh.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {

if (error) {
 console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
 return;
 };
whoosh.play((success) => {
  if (success) {
  console.log('successfully finished playing');
  } else {
   console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
   reset the player to its uninitialized state (android only)
   whoosh.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is First to create a new instance like Following. 
     create this in a constructor to load it when the component mount
    Note: please put your mp3 or wav file in android/app/src/main/res/raw

```
const whoosh  = new Sound('swoosh.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE);
```

just call it in your function

```
whoosh.play()
```

Comment: And how is this different from the answer that was already there?

Comment: it's just a two-line code bro and easy to understand

Comment: In my experiment, the sound file must be referenced as `./swoosh.mp3`, not `swoosh.mp3` (note the preceding dot and slash), otherwise an error will be thrown during bundling (TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined in DeltaPatcher.js:77)

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install react-native-sound` and *link with your project.*
2. 

```
Import sound from react-native-sound
// or
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
```

3. Put your mp3 file inside the folder and mention the path:

```
const requireAudio = require('./xyz.mp3');
```

4. Place this code inside your "onPress" function.

```
    const s = new Sound(requireAudio, (e) => {
            if (e) {
              console.log('Error in SOUND', e);
              return;
            }
            s.play(() => s.release());
          });
```